# How can I set TextMate as the default application when clicking on filenames in iTerm?

Tags: shell, textmate, iterm

I'm using iTerm as my default bash shell with Mountain Lion

One of the features is when you click on a file name in the shell, it opens it in a TextEditor.

At the moment though, each time I click a filename it's opened in XCode :(

How can I set this to open in TextMate instead?

I've tried setting my `EDITOR` shell variable to `mate -w` but no luck :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing this is based on the default file type and if that is the case just type `open .`, click on the file and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>, scroll to the bottom and select "always open this type of file with".

Or with textmate you can simply type `mate filename` or `mate .` to open the directory as a project. This does require that you open up TextMate's preferences and enable the command line option.